# Android : Activity not called from BroadcastReceiver when app is in background

Tags: java, android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver

When app is open then its working fine but when app is in background then BroadcastReceiver is called but activity intent not working

```
  class FakeCallReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    
        override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent?) {
            
            LogUtils.d("===onReceive 1")
            setCustomSetting(context)
            LogUtils.d("===onReceive 2")
            val incomingCallActivity =  Intent(context.applicationContext, FakeCallActivity::class.java)
            incomingCallActivity.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
            context.startActivity(incomingCallActivity)
            LogUtils.d("===onReceive 3")
        }

        fun setCustomSetting(context: Context){
            val wakeLock: PowerManager.WakeLock =
                (context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE) as PowerManager).run {
                    newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "MyApp::MyWakelockTag").apply {
                        acquire()
                    }
                }
            val mKeyguard = (context.getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE) as KeyguardManager).apply {
                newKeyguardLock("MyApp::Keyguard").disableKeyguard()
            }        
        }
    }
```

All logs are print there is no exception is occur but still `FakeCallActivity` is not called

```
MinSdkVersion = 24
TargetSdkVersion = 29
```

**1. Have i made any mistake ?

2. Is there other way to open activity when app is in background ?**

Comment: have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/16666632

Comment: Can you add device details here? Also, add `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion`.

Comment: @Deepanshu  
`androidMinSdkVersion = 24
androidTargetSdkVersion = 29
device os version = 8.1`

Comment: @HimanshuChoudhary yes i tried this

Answer (score 1):

Starting Android 10 (API level 29), there are restrictions on opening an activity from the background. Check this - https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts.

You should try to avoid this or you can check these exceptions - https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts#exceptions. If any of the exceptions works for you then you can try doing that.

Comment: how TrueCaller open dialog and how whatsapp open instant reply dialog

Comment: @Sanjayrajsinh you can check the permissions which Truecaller takes. It takes some permissions which allows it to draw over other applications. And Whatsapp posts a notification instead of opening an activity. In Android, you can create notifications with reply capability.